# Regex in .htaccess - remove specific word(s)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to remove the `shop-single?id=` in the following url? `http://example.com/shop-single?id=test`

I've tried the following, which I've read in another post, but unfortunately did not work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)shop-single?id=(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1-$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Before doing this, I'm removing the .html like this (which works):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?jiphalk361\.361\.axc\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.1912websites.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+shop-single\?id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ shop-single.html?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be working, but the problem is that I'm getting 404 not found now. Is it possible to show the actual page from the original url while using these rewrite rules?

Comment: shop-single.html, it's a file

Comment: Same 404 error. The url is https://tastedbyfranc.1912websites.nl/el_castilla_viura_chardonnay where it was https://tastedbyfranc.1912websites.nl/shop-single?id=el_castilla_viura_chardonnay before

Comment: Can you copy/paste your latest .htacess in question with my suggested changes

Comment: This is my whole htaccess file: https://pastebin.com/75aWW42j. `https://tastedbyfranc.1912websites.nl/shop-single.html?id=el_castilla_viura_chardonnay` did work before

Comment: That doesn't work because it is `shop-single.html`, not `shop-single.htm`. The link works with `.html`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222109/discussion-between-anubhava-and-jip-harthoorn).